# Using Graphics.DrawImage , changes the background of my transparent PNG images , to black

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've write this method to resize my images, but the returned image for my transparent PNG images, has a black background.
What is the solution?

I've tried `Bitmap.MakeTransparent()` and also `Graphics.Clear()` but couldn't solve my problem.
I've checked all related questions, but couldn't find any useful answer to my question.

```
public HttpResponseMessage ImageResizer(string path, int w,int h)
    {

        var imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path); 
        Bitmap image;
        try
        {
            image = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        }
        catch
        {
            HttpResponseMessage hrm = new HttpResponseMessage();
            return hrm;
        }

        int originalWidth = image.Width;
        int originalHeight = image.Height;

        // New width and height based on aspect ratio
        int newWidth = w;
        int newHeight = h;

        // Convert other formats (including CMYK) to RGB.
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        // Draws the image in the specified size with quality mode set to HighQuality
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            using (var attribute = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                attribute.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);

                // draws the resized image to the bitmap
                graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
        }
        // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the PNG codec.
        ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = this.GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Png);

        // Create an Encoder object for the Quality parameter.
        Encoder encoder = Encoder.Quality;

        // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
        EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        // Save the image as a PNG file with quality level.
        EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(encoder, 10);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;
        var splitPath = imagePath.Split('.');
        string newPath = splitPath[0] + "ss5.png";
        newImage.Save(newPath, ImageFormat.Png);

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        newImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;
        return response;
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat format)
    {
        return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().SingleOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == format.Guid);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` in your `Bitmap` constructor. That format is limiting your bitmap to 3 channels: red, green, and blue. Because of this, the bitmap you are creating doesn't support alpha (a.k.a. transparency) and will default to a solid black image. When you draw an image with transparency in it, the alpha of that image will either be pre-multiplied or discarded, depending on its format.

If you want to save your new image with transparency, you need to declare it with `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`:

```
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution , it works great. Images were still loaded from browser cache and I thought your solution is not working. Thanks.